# Spring. Аннотация @Scope

Tags: spring, scope

Возможен ли неправильный переход с одной страницы на другую, при неправильно выбранном Scope? В программе используется переопределённый Scope

Comment: Если это так, то куда стоит обратить внимание?

Comment: Смотря насколько переопределенный и как у вас реализована логика перехода.